# Amazon Braket: how to search quantum tasks by tag

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, quantum-computing

Let's say I submit a batch of quantum tasks through Amazon Braket under a given tag e.g.

```py
from braket.aws import AwsDevice
from braket.circuits import Circuit

circuits = [Circuit(...), Circuit(...), ...]

device = AwsDevice(...)

task = device.run_batch(circuits, tags={"batch": "test"}, ...)
```

If I previously submitted a number of quantum tasks using the same tag as well, how can I get back all of my quantum tasks that match that tag key/value pair?

*My attempt*: I tried using [`botocore.client.Braket.search_quantum_tasks()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/braket/client/search_quantum_tasks.html) function e.g.

```py
import boto3

client = client("braket")

response = client.search_quantum_tasks(
    filters=[
        {
            'name': 'string',
            'operator': 'LT'|'LTE'|'EQUAL'|'GT'|'GTE'|'BETWEEN',
            'values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ],
    maxResults=123,
    nextToken='string'
)
```

but it's not clear how to use the supported `name`, `operator`, and `values` fields to filter over tags.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `resourcegroupstaggingapi` to retrieve the tasks with a specific tag, with something like the following:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
response = client.get_resources(
    TagFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'batch'
        },
    ],
)
tasks = [t["ResourceARN"] for t in response["ResourceTagMappingList"]]
```

Note that the `resourcegroupstaggingapi` boto client would need to be in the same region as the quantum tasks. You could initialize the client targeted to a specific region as follows:

```
# Replace eu-west-2 with the region you created the quantum tasks in
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', region_name="eu-west-2")
```